# Removing iframe

Tags: php, redirect, iframe

Don't know how to frase this but I found this code wich works as it should. However I don't want the redirect in an iframe! Basically what I want is the logged in user to be redirected to his own directory where only he has access to it, makes sense?

```
if($session->logged_in){

<echo"
iframe id=\"login-form\" frameborder=\"0\" scrolling=\"no\" width=\"100%\"     src=\"$serverroot.$session->directory/abc.php\" height=\"400\" align=\"left\"></iframe><br   /> 
";
```

Should be simple enough (not for me though... :)

Anyone care to chip in?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So then just do a header redirect:

```
header("Location: {$serverroot}{$session->directory}/abc.php");
exit; // just in case you have more code beneath you don't want to execute.
```

Comment: Thanks, however it skips the users directory and goes to my serverroot /abc.php

Comment: @user1424728 okay, but your iframe has the same `src` as in my answer; so I will need more background information

Comment: Ok, thanks to your input I finally put it all together and I put username instead of directory in the redirect! Thank you for helping out on this seemingly trivial problem! :)